# Image scaling on cylinder JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

What I want to do is scale an image on a cylinder in Java3D. The code I have so far is shown below. I have no clue how to make the image not stretch over the whole cylinder.

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Material;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Cylinder;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EarthCylinder extends Application {

    double anchorX, anchorY;

    private double anchorAngleX = 0;
    private double anchorAngleY = 0;

    private final DoubleProperty angleX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final DoubleProperty angleY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    PerspectiveCamera scenePerspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Remove this line once dirtyopts bug is fixed for 3D primitive        
        System.setProperty("prism.dirtyopts", "false");
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Image diffuseMap
                = new Image(EarthCylinder.class
                        .getResource("download.jpg")
                        .toExternalForm());

        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();      
        material.setDiffuseMap(diffuseMap);

        final Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(200, 400);

        cylinder.setMaterial(material);


        final Group parent = new Group(cylinder);
        parent.setTranslateX(450);
        parent.setTranslateY(450);
        parent.setTranslateZ(0);

        Rotate xRotate;
        Rotate yRotate;
        parent.getTransforms().setAll(
        xRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS),
        yRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS));
        xRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleX);
        yRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleY);
        final Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(parent);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 900, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            anchorX = event.getSceneX();
            anchorY = event.getSceneY();

            anchorAngleX = angleX.get();
            anchorAngleY = angleY.get();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            angleX.set(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - event.getSceneY()));
            angleY.set(anchorAngleY + anchorX - event.getSceneX());
        });

        PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
        pointLight.setTranslateX(400);
        pointLight.setTranslateY(400);
        pointLight.setTranslateZ(-3000);

        scene.setCamera(scenePerspectiveCamera);

        root.getChildren().addAll(pointLight, scenePerspectiveCamera);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The result of the above code is shown here:

[image]

Comment: An http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve may be helpful. However, the cylinder automatically creates texture coordinates for the `Shape3D` (that is, for the `Geometry` of the `Shape3D`) that it consists of. My quess would be that you manually have to obtain the `Shape3D` from the `Cylinder`, then the `Geometry` from the `Shape3D`, then the `GeometryArray` from the `Geometry`, and finally use something like http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/GeometryArray.html#setTextureCoordinates%28int,%20int,%20javax.vecmath.TexCoord2f[]%29 (I'd try it out if you posted a MCVE)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will upload the full code

Comment: Oh, sorry. that was a misunderstanding. This question is not about **Java3D** ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html ), but about **JavaFX**. (Although, obviously, they have adopted many of the elements from Java3D when they created the 3D-API for JavaFX ;-)).

Comment: Well, from a quick glance at the API and the code, there really seems to be **no** official way of changing the texture coordinates of a Cylinder. That's irritating. Of course one could create the cylinder geometry manually (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/graphics/rt/file/ab9489903f7b/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/shape/Cylinder.java#l379), but that should not be necessary. I'm curious whether someone finds an appropriate answer for this...

Comment: Yes it's really annoying. I found a way by adding another cylinder with a different height and radius +1. I added some whitespaces to the image to make sure the scaling of the image is done correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, scaling/padding the image to have width of `Math.PI*originalWidth` is an option, but I'd consider this has questionable, to say the least. In Java3D, you had the option to specify a *Texture Matrix* - a matrix that was applied to the texture coordinates. Before it became clear that it was about JavaFX, I tested this in Java3D, and a matrix with a scaling of `Math.PI, 1.0, 1.0` (for x,y,z) did the job. I wonder why they did not add this in JavaFX. So although it's a hassle, I'd give the manual geometry creation (with the code from the above link) a try...